# 12-factor authentication with Google service accounts from Colab notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, service-accounts, 12factor

I need to access my Google service account from within a Colab notebook.
Currently I have a private notebook where I do

```
token = {
# secret stuff
}
from google.oauth2 import service_account
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(token)
```

This is works for a private notebook, but the notebook cannot be shared.
I am looking for some 12-factor like mechanism that will work in Colab
the way `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` works on my local machine.

I would like to be able to share the notebook in a way where it transparently uses each users own service account credentials when they run it, preferably without having to click around in the browser to get a token the way the default Colab browser authentication does.

I thought about storing the token json file in gdrive, but that does not really help. You need to authenticate to mount the gdrive and and you would want to load each users respective file.

Comment: Embarassed to ask, but is this about "12 factor" or you mean 2FA (2-factor auth)? Asking as the question is also tagged [tag:12factor]